# Webscraping using Python - Link is unchanged with form input

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, mechanize

I planned to retrieve the historical data from the open web available. From the link:

https://www.entsoe.eu/db-query/consumption/mhlv-a-specific-country-for-a-specific-day

Ideally, I am trying to change the country, day,month,year using the inputs from a Pandas Dataframe and retrieve the results (energy consumption here in this web page) and store back to excel.

I am trying with different web scrappers and one information is doubtful to me about the possibilities.

It is : when I manually change the Country, day, month,year and when retriving results, the web link remains unchanged. Is it possible to achieve my goal with this web link.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The submitted data is being done via a POST request to the website, not a GET request, so the URL isn't going to change.  Multiple suggested frameworks will work for sending post requests, or by submitting the form.

Comment: You can use `Developer Tools` in Chrome/Firefox to see data in POST request.

Comment: Thanks very much @Rejected and furas for your knowledge sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand what happens when you click "Send" button. A POST request is sent to the same URL with parameters corresponding to values you've selected on the form. You can see this request in the browser developer tools - "Network" tab. Now, you need to simulate this request in your code (I'll use the awesome [`requests` package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) below)

The other problem is that if you inspect what you get in the response to that POST request, you would not find the same `table` element with the desired data as you would see in the browser. This is because the `table` is dynamically generated from the `myData` javascript variable "sitting" in on of the `script` elements. Since nor `BeautifiulSoup`, nor `requests` is a browser and cannot execute JavaScript, you need to extract the `myData` value from the script.

Here is a working code that would get you the desired data in the "archived" scope for 01/01/2009:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval
from pprint import pprint

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.entsoe.eu/db-query/consumption/mhlv-a-specific-country-for-a-specific-day"
data = {
    "opt_period": "2",
    "opt_Country": "3",
    "opt_Day": "1",
    "opt_Month": "1",
    "opt_Year": "2009",
    "opt_Response": "1",
    "send": "send"
}
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36'}
    # visit the page
    session.get(url)

    # make a POST request
    response = session.post(url, data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # find the desired script
    pattern = re.compile(r"var myData = (.*?);", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

    # extract the data from the script
    match = pattern.search(script.get_text())
    data = match.group(1).strip()
    data = literal_eval(data)

    pprint(data)
```

Prints a Python list of lists:

```
[['AT',
  '2009-01-01',
  6277,
  6002,
  5649,
  5230,
  5034,
  5038,
  4858,
  5127,
  5342,
  5747,
  6100,
  6373,
  6325,
  6210,
  6129,
  6160,
  6588,
  7007,
  7058,
  6887,
  6586,
  6137,
  6494,
  5974]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learned a lot from your answer. I highly respect your time,taken:)